# split string in subelements ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, nested-loops

I have a list of dicts and I want to loop through the list of dicts, and then have an inner loop that splits a string from each dict and loops through that split string. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried a few things:

```
- debug:
     msg: '{{ "Group: " + item.Group + ", AddMembers: " + item.1 }}'
  with_nested:
     - '{{ domainGroups.list | selectattr("AddMembers", "ne", "") | list }}'
     - '{{ AddMembers.split("|") }}'

- debug: 
    msg: '{{ "Group: " + item.Group + ", AddMembers: " + item.1 }}'
  loop: '{{ domainGroups.list | selectattr("AddMembers", "ne", "" ) | list | subelements(AddMembers.split("|")) }}'
```

The list of dicts:

```
        {
            "AddMembers": "",
            "Group": "Group1",
            "Delete": "1",

        },
        {
            "AddMembers": "members1|members2",
            "Group": "Group2",
            "Delete": "",
        },
        {
            "AddMembers": "members1|members2|members3",
            "Group": "Group3",
            "Delete": "",
        },
```

I hoped that one of the things I've tried would work but usually I get some variation of "AddMembers is not defined" or "unicode thing has no attribute "AddMembers""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Declare the variables

```yaml
  my_groups: "{{ domainGroups|map(attribute='Group')|list }}"
  my_member: "{{ domainGroups|map(attribute='AddMembers')|
                              map('split', '|')|
                              map('select')|list }}"
  groups_members: "{{ dict(my_groups|zip(my_member)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  groups_members:
    Group1: []
    Group2:
    - members1
    - members2
    Group3:
    - members1
    - members2
    - members3
```

Iterate with subelements

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Group: {{ item.0.key }} AddMember: {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ groups_members|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'Group: Group2 AddMember: members1'
  msg: 'Group: Group2 AddMember: members2'
  msg: 'Group: Group3 AddMember: members1'
  msg: 'Group: Group3 AddMember: members2'
  msg: 'Group: Group3 AddMember: members3'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    domainGroups:
      - AddMembers: ''
        Delete: '1'
        Group: Group1
      - AddMembers: members1|members2
        Delete: ''
        Group: Group2
      - AddMembers: members1|members2|members3
        Delete: ''
        Group: Group3

    my_groups: "{{ domainGroups|map(attribute='Group')|list }}"
    my_member: "{{ domainGroups|map(attribute='AddMembers')|
                                map('split', '|')|
                                map('select')|list }}"
    groups_members: "{{ dict(my_groups|zip(my_member)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: groups_members

    - debug:
        msg: "Group: {{ item.0.key }} AddMember: {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ groups_members|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

---

**Deprecated**

Let's simplify the dictionaries in the first step. The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        domainGroups_selected: "{{ domainGroups_selected|default([]) +
                                   [ {'Group': item.Group,
                                      'AddMembers': item.AddMembers.split('|')}] }}"
      loop: "{{ domainGroups }}"
      when: item.AddMembers|length > 0
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ domainGroups_selected }}"
```

give

```yaml
    "item": {
        "AddMembers": [
            "members1", 
            "members2"
        ], 
        "Group": "Group2"
    }
    ...
    "item": {
        "AddMembers": [
            "members1", 
            "members2", 
            "members3"
        ], 
        "Group": "Group3"
    }
```

Then loop the list with subelements. The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Group: {{ item.0.Group }} AddMember: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ domainGroups_selected|subelements('AddMembers')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "Group: Group2 AddMember: members1"
    "msg": "Group: Group2 AddMember: members2"
    "msg": "Group: Group3 AddMember: members1"
    "msg": "Group: Group3 AddMember: members2"
    "msg": "Group: Group3 AddMember: members3"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! :)